# How to get first few occurrences starting with a string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the first 3 occurrences (rows) in a MySQL table (column specified) that start with a user-provided string:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$user_input = $_POST['user_input'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM airports WHERE airport_name LIKE '$user_input%' LIMIT 3") or die();  
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$airport_suggestion1 = $row[1];
$airport_suggestion2 = $row[2];
$airport_suggestion3 = $row[3];
```

For some reason this will only return the first row found, $airport_suggestion2 and $airport_suggestion3 are always empty even when they shouldn't be. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe only one row matches.

Comment: Loop `mysqli_fetch_array`, it only returns one row without a loop....You also should not be putting user input directly into SQL. Parameterizing your query is best practice.

Comment: Right, I wouldn't run this in a live code without a mysqli_real_escape() on all user inputs before running SQL, I just didn't include it in the code for brevity.

Comment: @gonna_take_sometime Even [`real_escape_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2469308) cannot secure it completely. For more robustness, please use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)